# mysql query loading forever in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have no idea why the below is not working.  I have tested mysql on an alternative project, and it works.

Maybe you guys can see what I am not:  The User clicks the submit button:

HTML:

```
<form class='find_form'>
    <input class='find_value'/>
    <input class="find_submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".find_submit").click(function() {;
    var value = $('.find_value').val();
    if (value == false) { return false; } else {
        var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/forum/index.php/ajax/find_active",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {value: value}
        });
        request.done(function (response){
            console.log(response);
            //update history
            //update threads
            //update activecontent['thread_name']
            active(response['active']);
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

AJAX/find_active:

```
function find_active()
{
        $active = $this->input->post('value');
        $active_list = $this->search_model->find_active($active);
        //...//
}
```

search_model:

```
    public function find_active($active)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM keywords
                WHERE keywords.keyword 
                LIKE '%$active%'
                ORDER BY count DESC";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

After hitting submit, it runs ajax/find_active and in firebug, the wheel keeps turning until I get a memory error.

I have reverted back to a working revision, and added ONLY the query.  So I am 99% sure its whats causing the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running the query in the mysql cli or other interface such as phpMyAdmin to see if it loads slow there too? It could be returning too much data. Also, you should escape $active before running the query to make sure it's safe.

Comment: You have tested the query in `Mysql Administrator` or `Phpmyadmin`?

Comment: yes, it works fine inside phpmyadmin.

I've also tried it on 2 separate computers.  I should point out, this is running on xampp and local host.

Comment: try to `LIMIT` the records and see how it behaves

Comment: i added a `limit` saw no change.  I did however, completely remove the query, and replace with, `return 'test`' and am still getting the same problem??

Comment: Thank you for help. I figured it out.  I was loading `search_model` in search_models construct.  which was freezing the page.

Comment: yes u do see a problem... i would make sure u have the $action inside $this->db->escape($active);

Comment: or use query bindings

Comment: Thank you all.  I just started writing it, haven't escaped yet. But thank you for tips.